# Different session created in Laravel with every request

Tags: php, laravel, session

I've got the following issue: Whenever I make a single request towards Laravel the same session is used, whenever I make multiple Ajax requests then Laravel keeps creating new sessions.

I applied the StartSession and EncryptCookies middlewares on the API routes. My Kernel looks the following way:

```
    'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            'bindings',
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ],
```

Does any one have an idea why multiple new sessions are created when in practice the session cookie should get renewed about the already created session.

Comment: What are you using to test this?

Comment: I'm accessing a page where that page makes multiple ajax calls for fetching information from the api routes.

Comment: Your api routes will not handle session data as you expect. Apis are intended to be **stateless**, so it would be better to have another identifier (e.g. `api_key`) to identify the user/client.

Answer (score 0):

Http apps are stateless meaning you Sessions are manually handled for multi request.

Clean all session data

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

Generate a new session id

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

Latavel is not a framework that expects

Answer (score 0):

```
AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class
```

Should be:

```
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class
```

Here's my Kernel middlewareGroups for reference

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        'bindings',
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ],
];
```